# how to solve Error message I/O Error CPF5129 in RPGLE?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

please help,
we are having a problem with a RPG program

> Message . . . . : I/O is not allowed because the program device or My
> LF member in my library is in error. Cause . . . . . : An input/output
> (I/O) operation was requested for a file that is in error.

I/O error CPF5129 Was detected in my file.

error appears when SETLL in my LF

```
FZ8HY#     UF A E           K DISK                         
FZ8HYL1    UF   E           K DISK    Rename(AHY:AHY1)
F                                     Prefix(A)   

...

C     KEY03         KList                                        
C                   KFLD                    Wfnumb           10    
C                   Kfld                    WFvldt            8 0
C                   Kfld                    WFpodt            8 0

...

C                   MOVEL     *LOVAL        WFDTPO                     
**C     KEY03         SETLL     Z8HY#   (Error statement)  **                               
C                   READ(N)   Z8HY#                                  90
C     *in90         DOWEQ     *off
```

write and read file

Comment: There must be some message in the joblog that gives information about the error, please add it to your question.

Comment: Is this a new error? What has been changed to introduce it? Some errors can be caused by trying to e. g. CHAIN to a record by keyfield and no keyfields are in the PF/LF. Please include the LF definition.

Comment: no, this is old program. program has been live more than 5 years ago. I try to call manual, program run normally. joblog is "I/O is not allowed because the program device or member Z8HY# file Z8HY# in library XXXX is in error. I/O error CPF5129 Was detected in file Z8HY#. function check RNX1299 unmonitored by PROGRAM ......"